# Succah with mosquito netting

Tags: halacha, sukkah, bugs

Generally we are not allowed to put a tent taller than 10 tefachim inside of a succah.  But can one use mosquito netting inside of a succah that would allow in light but not dangerous insects?

Comment: _Mishna B'rura_ 629:58 says not to use a canopy hung for utility, even if it's near the _s'chach_, but notes that it's better to do so than to eat in the house (but then don't say a _b'racha_ on the _mitzva_ of eating in the _suka_). **However**, he's talking about one that blocks the light, whereas you're asking about one that doesn't, which is why I'm not posting this as an answer.

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3056

Answer (score 2):

(As with any practical halachic question, please consult with your own rabbi.)

**I.** See אור יצחק by יצחק עבאדי here :

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&pgnum=258

He allows such a netting.

**II.** A slightly different question is found here:

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49009&pgnum=200

The question is dealing with an open area surrounded by buildings, the top of which is covered by bird-netting. The author is lenient, but it should be noted that he's dealing with a case where there's no other place to build the סוכה.

Comment: I will try to add some of details of this rather long תשובה some time later.